# (When) are parallel sorts practical and how do you write an efficient one?

Tags: multithreading, sorting, scalability, parallel-processing, d

I'm working on a parallelization library for the D programming language.  Now that I'm pretty happy with the basic primitives (parallel foreach, map, reduce and tasks/futures), I'm starting to think about some higher level parallel algorithms.  Among the more obvious candidates for parallelization is sorting.

My first question is, are parallelized versions of sorting algorithms useful in the real world, or are they mostly academic?  If they are useful, where are they useful?  I personally would seldom use them in my work, simply because I usually peg all of my cores at 100% using a much coarser grained level of parallelism than a single sort() call.

Secondly, it seems like quick sort is almost embarrassingly parallel for large arrays, yet I can't get the near-linear speedups I believe I should be getting.  For a quick sort, the only inherently serial part is the first partition. I tried parallelizing a quick sort by, after each partition, sorting the two subarrays in parallel.  In simplified pseudocode:

```
// I tweaked this number a bunch.  Anything smaller than this and the 
// overhead is smaller than the parallelization gains.
const  smallestToParallelize = 500; 

void quickSort(T)(T[] array) {
    if(array.length < someConstant) {
        insertionSort(array);
        return;
    }

    size_t pivotPosition = partition(array);

    if(array.length >= smallestToParallelize) {
        // Sort left subarray in a task pool thread.
        auto myTask = taskPool.execute(quickSort(array[0..pivotPosition]));
        quickSort(array[pivotPosition + 1..$]);
        myTask.workWait();
    } else {
        // Regular serial quick sort.
        quickSort(array[0..pivotPosition]);
        quickSort(array[pivotPosition + 1..$]);
    }
}
```

Even for very large arrays, where the time the first partition takes is negligible, I can only get about a 30% speedup on a dual core, compared to a purely serial version of the algorithm.  I'm guessing the bottleneck is shared memory access.  Any insight on how to eliminate this bottleneck or what else the bottleneck might be?

Edit:  My task pool has a fixed number of threads, equal to the number of cores in the system minus 1 (since the main thread also does work).  Also, the type of wait I'm using is a work wait, i.e. if the task is started but not finished, the thread calling `workWait()` steals other jobs off the pool and does them until the one it's waiting on is done.  If the task isn't started, it is completed in the current thread.  This means that the waiting isn't inefficient.  As long as there is work to be done, all threads will be kept busy.

Comment: I don't know how to make your quicksort parallelize better, but there is a variant called samplesort which is inherently much faster than a vanilla quicksort, and as far as I can see, it should be equally parallelizable.

Answer (score 7):

Keep in mind I'm not an expert on parallel sort, and folks make research careers out of parallel sort but...

1) are they useful in the real world.

of course they are, if you need to sort something expensive (like strings or worse) and you *aren't* pegging all the cores.

- think UI code where you need to sort a large dynamic list of strings based on context
- think something like a barnes-hut n-bodies sim where you need to sort the particles

2) Quicksort seems like it would give a linear speedup, but it isn't.  The partition step is a sequential bottleneck, you will see this if you profile and it will tend to cap out at 2-3x on a quad core.

If you want to get good speedups on a smaller system you need to ensure that your per task overheads are really small and ideally you will want to ensure that you don't have too many threads running, i.e. not much more than 2 on a dual core.  A thread pool probably isn't the right abstraction.

If you want to get good speedups on a larger system you'll need to look at the scan based parallel sorts, there are papers on this. bitonic sort is also quite easy parallelize as is merge sort.  A parallel radix sort can also be useful, there is one in the PPL (if you aren't averse to Visual Studio 11).

Answer (score 3):

*I'm no expert* but... here is what I'd look at:

First of all, I've heard that as a rule of thumb, algorithms that look at small bits of a problem from the start tends to work better as parallel algorithms.

Looking at your implementation, try making the parallel/serial switch go the other way: partition the array and sort in parallel until you have N segments, then go serial. If you are more or less grabbing a new thread for each parallel case, then N should be ~ your core count. OTOH if your thread pool is of fixed size and acts as a queue of short lived delegates, then I'd use N ~ 2+ times your core count (so that cores don't sit idle because one partition finished faster).

Other tweaks:

- skip the `myTask.wait();` at the local level and rather have a wrapper function that waits on all the tasks.
- Make a separate serial implementation of the function that avoids the depth check.

Answer (score 1):

"My first question is, are parallelized versions of sorting algorithms useful in the real world" - depends on the size of the data set that you are working on in the real work. For small sets of data the answer is no. For larger data sets it depends not only on the size of the data set but also the specific architecture of the system.

One of the limiting factors that will prevent the expected increase in performance is the cache layout of the system. If the data can fit in the L1 cache of a core, then there is little to gain by sorting across multiple cores as you incur the penalty of the L1 cache miss between each iteration of the sorting algorithm.

The same reasoning applies to chips that have multiple L2 caches and NUMA (non-uniform memory access) architectures. So the more cores that you want to distribute the sorting across, the smallestToParallelize constant will need to be increased accordingly.

Another limiting factor which you identified is shared memory access, or contention over the memory bus. Since the memory bus can only satisfy a certain number of memory accesses per second; having additional cores that do essentially nothing but read and write to main memory will put a lot of stress on the memory system.

The last factor that I should point out is the thread pool itself as it may not be as efficient as you think. Because you have threads that steal and generate work from a shared queue, that queue requires synchronization methods; and depending on how those are implemented, they can cause very long serial sections in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if answers here are applicable any longer or if my suggestions are applicable to D.

Anyway ...

Assuming that D allows it, there is always the possibility of providing prefetch hints to the caches. The core in question requests that data it will soon (not immediately) need be loaded into a certain cache level. In the ideal case the data will have been fetched by the time the core starts working on it. More likely the prefetch process will be more or less on the way which at least will result in less wait states than if the data were fetched "cold."

You'll still be constrained by the overall cache-to-RAM throughput capacity so you'll need to have organized the data such that so much data is in the core's exclusive caches that it can spend a fair amount of time there before having to write updated data.

The code and data need to be organized according to the concept of cache lines (fetch units of 64 bytes each) which is the smallest-sized unit in a cache. This should result in that for two cores the work needs to be organized such that the memory system works half as much per core (assuming 100% scalability) as before when only one core was working and the work hadn't been organized. For four cores a quarter as much and so on. It's quite a challenge but by no means impossible, it just depends on how imaginative you are in restructuring the work. As always, there are solutions that cannot be conceived ... until someone does just that!

I don't know how WYSIWYG D is compared to C - which I use - but in general I think the process of developing scaleable applications is ameliorated by how much the developer can influence the compiler in its actual machine code generation. For interpreted languages there will be so much memory work going on by the interpreter that you risk not being able to discern improvements from the general "background noise."

I once wrote a multi-threaded shellsort which ran 70% faster on two cores compared to one and 100% on three cores compared to one. Four cores ran slower than three. So I know the dilemmas you face.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point you to External Sorting[1] which faces similar problems. Usually, this class of algorithms is used mostly to cope with large volumes of data, but their main point is that they split up large chunks into smaller and unrelated problems, which are therefore really great to run in parallel. You "only" need to stitch together the partial results afterwards, which is not quite as parallel (but relatively cheap compared to the actual sorting).

An External Merge Sort would also work really well with an unknown amount of threads. You just split the work-load arbitrarily, and give each chunk of n elements to a thread whenever there is one idle, until all your work units are done, at which point you can start joining them up.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting